# Eigen::Map and dimension change 4 to 3

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

#### Context:

I  want to operate rotations and scaling on an existing array, representing a 4x4 matrix, using Eigen.

I don't know how to do it without copying data around:

**Edit**: Input matrix is of type array<double,16>

#### The code:

Rotation:

```
    Eigen::Map <Eigen::Matrix4d> mapped_data( (double *)&input_matrix );
    auto rot = Eigen::AngleAxisf( angle_z, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ() );
    mapped_data *= rot.matrix();
```

Scale:

```
    Eigen::Map <Eigen::Matrix4d> mapped_data( (double *)&input_matrix );
    auto scaler = Eigen::Scaling(sx, sy, sz);
    mapped_data *= scaler;
```

Obviously it tells me that I cannot do it because of matrices of different sizes.

#### Constraint:

Again, I don't want to copy, so Map should be what I am after, but it only allows plain matrices (matrix2x, 3x or 4x) to be used (am I wrong?).

#### Question:

How to modify my code to make it work, with no useless copies?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the input matrix, a transformation matrix? Correct me if I'm wrong but if you add new transformation, such as a rotation, to an existing transformation matrix, doesn't the new part go on the left side of the matrix multiplication? So shouldn't the first expression be ```mapped_data = rot.matrix() * mapped_data```? Same with scaler.

Comment: Input matrix is a array<double,16>.. you are right for the order overlooked this! I will try tomorrow morning and report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen's geometry module has a handy [Transform](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html) class that helps with this stuff. Something like this should work:

```
using Affine3d = Eigen::Transform<double, 3, Eigen::Affine>;
double angle_z = ..., sx = ..., sy = ..., sz = ...;
Affine3d transform =
      Eigen::AngleAxisd(angle_z, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ())
      * Eigen::Scaling(sx, sy, sz);
mapped_data = mapped_data * transform.matrix();
```

Two notes:

1. Please double-check whether to apply the transformation on the left or right side. I always mess this up but I think the given order is correct (first rotate, then scale)
2. You used `AngleAxisf` but then want to combine it with a matrix of doubles. I changed everything to doubles for consistency but `Eigen::Transform` also has a `cast` method if you really want to compute the rotation at reduced precision

Comment: That transformation part is exactly what I needed. Even though I read the doc, for some reason, it wasn't clear to me. Now it is. Thanks